# 'Intent cannot be resolved to a type' error in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, adt

I am programming the first [android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) in eclipse, and when compiling this code:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

it gives the error

> Intent cannot be resolved to a type

How do I fix it?

Comment: Can you show us your activity class?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Probably, the `import` statement is missing. Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, Eclipse will automatically add the import statement if missing.

Then look at the top of the file and see what has been added. It should be something like this:

```
import android.content.Intent;
```