# Can't transition from a Dialog to an Activity

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, android-activity

I can't seem to transition from a Dialog to an Activity and I was wondering if anyone is clever enough to figure out why!

This is the last bug I need to fix before submitting this project.

package com.mkyong.android;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class AppActivity extends Activity {

final Context context = this;
private Button button;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    // add button listener
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Settings Menu");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Link or Delete?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Link",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
            //start new activity

            Intent intentApp2Activity = new Intent(AppActivity.this, App2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intentApp2Activity);

            // if this button is clicked, close
            // current activity
            AppActivity.this.finish();
        }
      })
            .setNegativeButton("Delete",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

```
03-02 08:16:32.219: E/AndroidRuntime(5484): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-02 08:16:32.219: E/AndroidRuntime(5484): java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
03-02 08:16:32.219: E/AndroidRuntime(5484): Intent cannot be resolved to a type
03-02 08:16:32.219: E/AndroidRuntime(5484): Intent cannot be resolved to a type
03-02 08:16:32.219: E/AndroidRuntime(5484): at com.mkyong.android.AppActivity$1$1.onClick(AppActivity.java:44)
03-02 08:16:32.219: E/AndroidRuntime(5484): at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
03-02 08:16:32.219: E/AndroidRuntime(5484): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-02 08:16:32.219: E/AndroidRuntime(5484): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-02 08:16:32.219: E/AndroidRuntime(5484): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-02 08:16:32.219: E/AndroidRuntime(5484): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 08:16:32.219: E/AndroidRuntime(5484): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-02 08:16:32.219: E/AndroidRuntime(5484): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-02 08:16:32.219: E/AndroidRuntime(5484): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-02 08:16:32.219: E/AndroidRuntime(5484): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you please explain what issue are you facing and is there any exception

Comment: Apologies - Force Close after clicking "Link" (which is supposed to transition to the other activity)

Comment: Post the logcat stack trace please.  BTW, the "paypal" thing is neither wanted nor desired.  I've edited it out.  This is a free community managed by volunteers for the good of the community.

Comment: Please post your Log cat trace

Comment: @AmaniSwann : make sure u have added App2Activity Activity in AndroidManifest.xml file. if yes then u have issue inside App2Activity Activity instead of AppActivity .so u will need to add App2Activity class code with Log cat trace

Comment: It's already in the Manifest and I can access it successfully independently and via 2 other buttons - just not the dialog script.


LOG CAT: 
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bzs014LBJ1sWMjRPT1VwOEdQNWc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804112/intent-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-error-in-eclipse

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124788/java-unresolved-compilation-problem - does your code even compile?

Comment: Look like import android.content.Intent is missing

Comment: Add this line in your imports:..

import android.content.Intent;

Comment: Awesome!!! Thanks Hoan! / Karan! You got it!!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have imported android.content.Intent, clean your project and rebuild.

This is a flaky piece of Android.  As the exception hints, you have an unresolved compile time problem which *should* produce a compile time error.  Smells like a bug in the ADT or Eclipse (I assume that you are using Eclipse) to me.