# 'Intent cannot be resolved to a type' error in eclipse and cannot import 'android.content.intent' on Mac

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

I am programming the first android tutorial in eclipse, and when compiling this code: Intent intent = getIntent(); it gives the error Intent cannot be resolved to a type. I have tried several times to import the 'android.content.intent' with no success.  How do I fix it please?

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage (View veiw) {
        //  Do something in response to button 
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);

    }

}
```

========
**DisplayMessageActvity.java**

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();
}

/**
 * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void setupActionBar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
        // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
        // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
        // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
        //
        // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
        //
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Comment: post your logcat message also.

Comment: "I have tried several times to import the 'android.content.intent' with no success". What do you mean by "tried several times"? By clicking on the quick help in Eclipse?

Comment: to import necessary files into program using eclipse just press Ctrl+Shift+O all files are imported automatically.

Comment: OK.  I added the line "import android.content.Intent;".  I ran the code again and got some additional errors for the intents but the first one appears to be gone.  I was unaware I could just type the lines of code and apologize for the confusion.

Comment: That is why I was frustrated.  It would not import with Ctrl+Shift+O

Comment: possible duplicate of ['Intent cannot be resolved to a type' error in eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804112/intent-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-error-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't imported `Intent` in your `DisplayMessageActivity` class. See the import clauses at the top? There's no `Intent` in there.

Comment: this must be comment not answer.

Comment: @RupeshNerkar No... this is an answer. And the correct answer at that.

Comment: @Kayaman: Surely it is the cause for the error and solution is to import it. But did you notice a line- **"I have tried several times to import the 'android.content.intent' with no success"** ?

Comment: The code he posted hasn't got the import. My answer provides a solution for that. If he claims that he **cannot** write "import android.content.Intent;" in his other class, then he's bullshitting me. And I don't tolerate bullshit, or your useless comments.

Comment: OK. I added the line "import android.content.Intent;". I ran the code again and got some additional errors for the intents but the first one appears to be gone. I was unaware I could just type the lines of code and apologize for the confusion

Comment: @user2995096 Even with advanced tools, most of the programming is done by typing out the code. If you don't learn to *write* code, you won't get very far in your programming career.